# How does one switch from a 5GHz to 2.4GHz band?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, time-capsule

I am trying to figure out how to switch the band on my router, using an Apple Time Capsule, MacBook Pro 2017. Is this possible? I want to be on 2.4GHz. I have this new Amazon Wand and it will not set up on 5GHz. Can anyone help?

Comment: Unless you disabled 2.4GHz band, it's transmits simultaneously with 5GHz.  If it is disabled, you just need to enable it.

Comment: Once you figure out if it was dis/enabled, write up your solution as an answer; I'll upvote so you can gain some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I ended up fixing this issue was by resetting my network from scratch. The 2.4GHz network/channel (as well as the 5GHz) became available/enabled and I used it to set up the device.